# How to convert JOSM MapCSS to SLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld, josm

I've found an important style file, but it is only in MapCSS format:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenSeaMap/josm/master/INT1_Seamark.mapcss

I need to convert it to SLD to use in Geoserver. Can someone show me in a simple example how to start my job?

You can use this as start point:

```
/* Q: Buoys, Beacons */
node["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark {
    icon-image:     eval(concat("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenSeaMap/josm/master/icons/svg/Q/Q9/", replace(replace(tag("seamark:daymark:shape"), " ", "_"), ",", ""), "/", any(replace(tag("seamark:daymark:colour"), ";", "_"), "generic"), ".svg"));
    icon-width:     16;
}
node["seamark:type"=buoy_lateral]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=beacon_lateral]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=buoy_cardinal]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=beacon_cardinal]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=buoy_isolated_danger]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=beacon_isolated_danger]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=buoy_safe_water]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=beacon_safe_water]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=buoy_special_purpose]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark,
node["seamark:type"=beacon_special_purpose]["seamark:daymark:shape"]::int1_daymark {
    icon-offset-x:  1;
    icon-offset-y:  -20;
}
```

---

```
<PointSymbolizer>
  <Graphic>

    <ExternalGraphic>
      <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="seamarks/Q/Q9/ dont know how to concat" />
      <Format>image/png</Format>
    </ExternalGraphic>
    <Size>16</Size>

  </Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
```

PS: Not work in CSS module.

EDIT: Table.

```
CREATE TABLE public.buoy_lateral
(
  way geometry(Point,900913),
  "seamark:name" text,
  "seamark:topmark:shape" text,
  "seamark:topmark:colour" text,
  "seamark:light:period" text,
  "seamark:light:character" text,
  "seamark:light:colour" text,
  "seamark:light:group" text
)
```

Comment: What is the `::int1_daymark` in CSS above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a [Dynamic Symbolizer](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html#dynamic-symbolizers) - then you can create resources like this if you have a simple concatenation:

```
<ExternalGraphic>
   <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"
                   xlink:href="http://mysite.com/tn_${STATE_ABBR}.jpg"/>
   <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
</ExternalGraphic>
```

or like this if you need a more complex formula:

```
<ExternalGraphic>
   <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"
            xlink:href="http://mysite.com/tn_${strToLowerCase(STATE_ABBR)}.jpg" />
   <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
</ExternalGraphic>
```

So in your example it looks like something like:

```
xlink:href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenSeaMap/josm/master/icons/svg/Q/Q9/${strReplace(strReplace(seamark:daymark:shape", " ", "_"), ",", "")/strReplace(tag("seamark:daymark:colour"), ";", "_")generic.svg}"
```

Might work - though you probably need to change the property names to  not have `:` in them.

Comment: Bravo! The `: ` came from OSM data..... I can't avoid. It may causing troble because I can't put a simple `xlink:href="seamarks/Q/Q9/cylinder/${seamark:topmark:colour}.svg"`  to work

Comment: so did that actually work? cool

Comment: Huh... see my edit.

Comment: a quick experiment suggests the the : are replaced by _ in GeoServer - check on the layer->data tab to see what your attributes are really called

Comment: Its the column names ( key values ). Have the `:` for sure. See my question edit.

Comment: Got an `Invalid cql expression` when using your answer. But to start simple I'll try to put `"seamarks/Q/Q9/cylinder/${seamark:topmark:colour}.svg"` to work first...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't do a `all-in-one-step` as suggested by @Iant... I'll need a `if..then..else` ECQL skill ....

First step: drop the layer table and recreate it with some friendly column names:

```
CREATE TABLE public.buoy_lateral (
  way geometry(Point,900913),
  name text,
  topmark_shape text,
  topmark_colour text,
  period text,
  "character" text,
  light_colour text,
  light_group text
)
```

Now I can put the simplest example to work as I wish (after recreate the layer, of corse):

```
     <PointSymbolizer>
       <Graphic>

          <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="seamarks/Q/Q9/cylinder/${topmark_colour}.svg" />
            <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
          </ExternalGraphic>
          <Size>16</Size>

         </Graphic>
     </PointSymbolizer>
```

As some data are empty, I need a filter:

```
     <ogc:Filter>
       <ogc:Not>
       <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
         <ogc:PropertyName>topmark_colour</ogc:PropertyName>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
       </ogc:Not>  
     </ogc:Filter>
```

A little CSS experiment... much more readable:

```
[topmark_colour = 'red'] {
     mark: url("file://seamarks/Q/Q9/cylinder/red.svg");
     mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";
     mark-size: 16;
}

[topmark_colour = 'green'] {
     mark: url("seamarks/Q/Q9/cylinder/green.svg");
     mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";
     mark-size: 16;
}
```

Now I'll try the complex way.... to be continued....

Comment: It's a very hard biblic work to convert MapCSS to SLD. I think I need to start a collaborative project in GitHub to get some help.

Comment: there is an if_then_else function - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#control-functions

Comment: The objective here is to take a  JOSM MapCSS and convert to SLD but I can't find any tutorial for MapCSS sintax... It is harder for me to understand what the MapCSS are doing than to find what to do in SLD.